# Google charts: Move legend position

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to visualize data on my website. I have a problem with the 'visualization' 1.1 and the 'pakcages' line:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
```

I try to put the legend column in the bottom position, with others Google Charts types I use the next line and it works:

```
var options = {
legend: { position: 'bottom'}
};
```

But with this type of charts no works, it put the legend column in the right, like you can see in this image of my web:
[chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeZal.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the syntax is like this:

```
var options = {
legend: 'bottom'
};
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_customizing_chart)

EDIT:
Actually, it seems to not yet be supported. Only right or none.
[Source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes?hl=en)

Comment: Hi Itamar. Thanks but no works. If you see the HTML code example of 'Creating Material Line Charts' in [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts) and use the syntax of your anwers or mine the legend always be in the right

Comment: Hm - works in classic - broken in Material. Seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1964

Comment: Edited answer - it seems to not be supported yet: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

Syntax would be -

```
  legend: { 
          position: 'bottom', 
        alignment: 'center' ,
        orientation: 'vertical',
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
```